# iPhone OS 3.2 equivalent of [CALayer contentsScale]?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, calayer

Hey I'm trying to do the equivalent thing that the iOS 4.0 method CALayer::contentsScale does, which scales the size of the backing bitmap of the layer. Any way to do this in iOS 3.2, probably by setting the frame size and applying a transform?

Answer (score 4):

You can scale a layer in all iOS versions by applying a scaling affine transform to the layer, e.g.:

```
CGAffineTransform scaleTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2.0, 2.0);
[myLayer setAffineTransform:scaleTransform];
```

I'm not familiar with the subtleties of behavior of the layer's contentsScale property-- this is probably not a drop-in replacement for it, but depending on what your use case is, might accomplish what you want just fine.

If you're just doing a scale, then the `position` of the layer should be the same as the `anchorPoint`, and you'll scale about the center, which is probably what you want. If you want to do anything more complex, be sure to understand what the anchor point is. [(Docs here)](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/Layers.html)